# Why is jQuery append duplicating my content?

Tags: jquery, append

When i use appendBox function below, first time it works fine and the same with removeBox, but second time it doesn't work properly: it duplicates my content.

What is wrong?

```
function appendBox( id )
{
    $("#listContainer").append("<div id=\"appendbox-"+ id +"\"><a href=\"javascript:removeBox("+ id +");\">remove</a></div>");
    $("#addBox-"+ id ).slideUp();
}
function removeBox( id )
{
    $("#listMyBoxs").append("<div id=\"addBox-"+ id +"\"><a href=\"javascript:appendBox("+ id +");\">tilføj</a></div>");
    $("#appendbox-"+ id ).slideUp();
}
```

this its my html when i try this test

```
<div style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">

    <div id="listContainer"></div>

    <div id="listMyBoxs">

        <div id="addBox-1">
            <a href="javascript:appendBox( 1 );">tilføj</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How are you using those functions?

Comment: What content does it duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the way you're doing it. A more typical solution would like this:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="listContainer"></div>
  <div id="listMyBoxes">
    <a href="#">tilføj</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

with:

```
#outer { height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; }
#outer a { display: block; }
```

and

```
$(function() {
  $("#listContainer a").live("click", function() {
    $(this).slideUp(function() {
      $(this).appendTo("#listMyBoxes").text("remove").slideDown();
    });
    return false;
  });
  $("#listMyBoxes a").live("click", function() {
    $(this).slideUp(function() {
      $(this).appendTo("#listContainer").text("tilføj").slideDown();
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Adjust as required. If you need more complex content than a simple link then you can enclose that in a div and adjust as necessary. The principles are all the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move an *existing element*, try:

```
$("#appendbox-"+ id ).appendTo('#listMyBoxs');
```

Using `$("<div></div>")` or `.append("<div></div>")` creates a new element.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue here, I used to append content to page using javascript and jQuery, it works fine at Chrome, but when trying it with Firefox it duplicates the appended content.

Here is an example:
[image: duplicate appeneded content]

I use this code to append content to a div:

```
function PlayGames() {
    $(".gameActions, #flash-game").show();
    $(".TheGame").show().append("<object id='flash-game' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' height='100%' width='100%' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' data='URL'>");
        }
```

Don't know why this happens only in Firefox and IE sometimes.